# How to print single lines from file

Tags: python, loops, command-line

Okay I'm trying to open a file then read the first line and have it print the first line. Once I get it to do that properly i plan on making a loop to repeat those steps for the remaining lines of that file. The issue that I keep having with the file I wrote below is it keeps printing out all the lines in the file opposed to just the first line, and its leaving a space between each line

```
import sys

def main():
    log1 = (sys.argv[1])
    log2 = (sys.argv[2])

    f = open(log1, 'r')
    for line1 in f:
        print (line1)

main()
```

Comment: It's double spaced because you have your endlines plus an extra line per print statement, unless you give it an end = ''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well, your code is exactly doing what you describe as an issue:

```
# open file
f = open(log1, 'r')
# for each line of the file
for line1 in f:
    # print the line
    print (line1)
```

so what you may want is:

```
import sys

def main():
    log1 = sys.argv[1]
    log2 = sys.argv[2]

    with open(log1, 'r') as f:
        # print that first line only
        print (f.readline().strip('\n'))

        # print the other lines
        for l in f:
            print(l.strip('\n'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

here, you can see a few modifications:

- to answer your questions:

  - `f.readline()` prints out only one time (consider it somehowe like one iteration of the `for` loop) ;
  - `l.strip('\n')` is for removing the `\n` character at the end of each line of the file so you don't have double carriage return for each line you `print()` ; to achieve the same result, you can also do `print(l, end='')` so you remove the `\n` from the print statement… Choose the one you prefer to remove! ;-)
- as a bonus to improve your code:

  - `with open(log1) as f:` is for using the context manager that will take care to `flush()` and `close()` the file once you're done with it ;
  - `if __name__ == "__main__":` is for executing the main() function automatically *only* when you run your module as a script, not when you import it into another code ;

Comment: Hey, I see you would up doing some things I suggested, good idea.

Comment: local variable "l'" referenced before assignment error

Comment: `print (l.readline().strip('\n'))` should be `print (f.readline().strip('\n'))`

Comment: sorry for that, it has been a typo – muscle lapsus – while writing it :-) That happens when I'm not coding with my beloved [editor](http://vim.org)

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
# if python2 uncomment next line:
# from __future__ import print_function
import sys

def main():
    log1 = (sys.argv[1])
    log2 = (sys.argv[2])
    # context manager automatically closes file if error
    # use 'U' flag for Universal readline mode (best practice)
    with open(log1, 'rU') as f: 
        # use the next function to get the first iteration from the file generator
        print(next(f)) 
        # uncomment following lines when ready to continue:
        # for line in f:
            # print(line, end='') 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```